# C# compiler VS C++ compiler (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, c++, performance, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I get many complains from our C# team about long compile times.

It looks like the compiler is always rebuilding the complete project even if you just change a single line of code.
The C++ team doesn't have this problem. After most edits it just takes a second to have the application running again.

Why is the C# compiler so different?

Note:
Our C# projects are in Visual Studio 2013, the C++ projects still in VS 2005. If I change a header in a C++ project it can take a while to compile but if I change code only it will just compile the changed file.

Comment: you should add tags then, not just correct the title.

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing your setup. Perhaps your C++ project is better compartmentalized while your C# project isn't. Can you describe your build setup in detail? Also, are we talking about the old C# compiler or Roslyn?

Comment: Funny because historically it's the other way around. C++ changes to header files cause all dependent code to be recompiled. In C#, lacking header files, _all_ code is potentially dependent, but for this reason C# compilers have been optimized to deal with this.

Comment: Badly formed solution can cause full rebuild on any change. For example it is enough to have single .jpg with "copy-always" in shared library to cause rebuild of whole solution. Add screenshot of solution tree/dependency diagram/paint masterpiece describing your solution.